# How to optimize proc sql with two group by statement?

Tags: sas

This peiece of code uses 2 sql query, the first uses `group by make` and the second uses `group by make, type`, and plus a statement to merge these 2 query results.

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table tab1 as
  select make, count(1) as total
  from sashelp.cars
  where origin='Asia'
  group by make;

  create table tab2 as
  select make, type, count(1) as count
  from sashelp.cars
  where origin='Asia'
  group by make, type;

  create table tab3 as 
  select a.*, b.type, b.count
  from tab1 as a
  left join tab2 as b on a.make=b.make
  order by make, type;
quit;
```

I make a shorter version like this:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table tab3 as 
  select *, sum(count) as sum
  from (
    select make, type, count(1) as count
    from sashelp.cars
    where origin='Asia'
    group by make, type
  )
  group by make
  order by make, type;
quit;
```

Is there a more simple and compact way?
Other procedures even data step are welcomed, but sql way is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `TABULATE` for your counting.

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.cars out=counts;
  class make type;
  table make*(type all), n;
  where origin = 'Asia';
run;

data want;
  merge 
    counts(where=(_type_='10') rename=n=total)
    counts(where=(_type_='11') rename=n=count)
  ;
  by make;
  drop _:;
run;
```

or use hashes to track your aggregates

```
data want(keep=make type count total);
  if 0 then set sashelp.cars;
  retain one 1;
  length count total 8;

  declare hash _2(keysum:'count', suminc:'one', ordered:'a');
  _2.defineKey('make', 'type');
  _2.defineDone();

  declare hash _1(keysum:'total', suminc:'one');
  _1.defineKey('make');
  _1.defineDone();

  do while (not end);
    set sashelp.cars end=end;
    _2.ref();
    _1.ref();
  end;

  declare hiter _2iter('_2');
  do while (_2iter.next()=0);
    _2.sum(sum:count);
    _1.sum(sum:total);
    output;
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count by make and also make*type in one pass then use PROC SUMMARY.

```
proc summary data=sashelp.cars ;
  where origin='Asia' ;
  class make type;
  types make make*type ;
  output out=want(rename=(_freq_=count));
run;
```